# Jongo MongoCollection.insert(String query) is parsing # as a param. How to avoid it

Tags: mongodb, insert, token, param, jongo

I am invoking the mongoCollection.insert(String query) method of jongo, inorder to insert a JSON into the collection. The JSON contains a # character in the field value. 
But since # is used as a query param token indicator, I will end up getting an parse error with "Not enough parameters passed to query" message.

How can I save a dynamic JSON string (note that I don't know the structure or schema of the JSON) which contains # character

Example:
{ 
  "order_id":"123445",
  "order_name":"test val#1"
}

The "test val#1" is just a string value which the user has entered. I would not like to encode every field value and it might not even be possible in my case. Please let me know if there is a work around.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the token used by Jongo by instanciating a custom BsonQueryFactory.
Nevertheless this token will be used for all queries in your application.

If you just want to change the token for a single query, you can pass the string with "#" as parameter :

```
@Test
public void canFindAndInsertWithHash() throws Exception {

    collection.insert("{name:#}", "test val#1");

    Friend friend = collection.findOne("{name:#}", "test val#1").as(Friend.class);

    assertThat(friend).isNotNull();
    assertThat(friend.getName()).isEqualTo("test val#1");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But it looks like this work around to pass # as a parameter will not work due to a bug or a feature in Jongo. It will replace # with {$marshall:0} even though its within quotes (""). Ultimately we will get com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException from mongo driver.
To be more clear, if I try collection.insert("{name:test val#1}", "somestring"); I will get an exception

Comment: Don't you think the BsonQueryFactory.createQuery method should only consider # if it represents the entire property name or property value (like {name:#}) and ignore the # which is part of a value string (like {name:test val#1})

Comment: @DPL, are you trying to insert the string "test valsomestring1"? If not I don't understand why you would attempt to execute `collection.insert("{name:test val#1}", "somestring");`  If you want to insert "test val#1" why doesn't Benoit's code work for you?

Comment: Paul, sorry if I was not clear. The above was an example. I am trying to insert "test val#1". But as I mentioned earlier in my question, I am getting the complete JSON from the client. I dont parse it, but rather insert it directly into Mongodb. I tried Benoit's answer: collection.insert("{name:test val#1}", "#"), but it will not work as we end up getting the JSON {name:test val{$marshall:0}1}, which is sent to the mongo driver. The mongo driver cannot parse this JSON and will throw JSONParseException

Comment: Hello I have added a test with an hash into parameter : https://github.com/bguerout/jongo/blob/b1e8307f8bc0442cf7c4946a80cbcb9f03ecf636/src/test/java/org/jongo/marshall/ParameterQueryBindingTest.java#L186 Does this test represents what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: No, All I am trying to do is collection.insert("{name:test val#1}");
Trying to insert a simple JSON which has a # character in it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same pb and i solve it by duplicating the org.jongo.marshall.mapper.JacksonMapper but changing line 60 by :

```
queryFactory = new BsonQueryFactory(jacksonEngine, "#|#");
```

where #|# is my new pattern...

Then I do :

```
Mapper jm = new JacksonMapperCustom.Builder().build();
Jongo jongo = new Jongo(db, jm);
```

And it works well !